# How to use annotationSaveMode = PSPDFAnnotationSaveModeExternalFile for bookmark PSPDFKit 6.6?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode8, pspdfkit

I want to save the bookmark of PDF externally for a multiple users. Earlier, I am using PSPDFKit 5.4 in that it is working fine, currently I am using PSPDFKit 6.6 in that its not saving bookmark but works fine for annotation.

```
__weak typeof (self) weakSelf = self;
document.didCreateDocumentProviderBlock = ^(PSPDFDocumentProvider *documentProvider) {
    documentProvider.annotationManager.fileAnnotationProvider.annotationsPath = [documentProvider.document.dataDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"annotations_%@.pspdfkit", weakSelf.currentUsername]];
};

// This example will only work for external file save mode.
document.annotationSaveMode = PSPDFAnnotationSaveModeExternalFile;

self.documentInfoCoordinator.availableControllerOptions = @[PSPDFDocumentInfoOptionBookmarks];
```

This will work fine when we use "PSPDFDocumentInfoOptionAnnotations" in place of "PSPDFDocumentInfoOptionBookmarks" for saving annotation, but not works for bookmark.

Please suggest if anyone have any idea how we save Bookmark of in PSPSDKit externally.

Answer (score 0):

Founder of the PSPDFKit SDK for iOS, Android and Web.

We're constantly improving our framework documentation, here's a preview of the bookmark guide that should answer your question:

https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/nightly/miscellaneous/bookmarks/

Once PSPDFKit 6.7 for iOS is released, it will include a sample that writes bookmark data into a CSV as part of our [PSPDFCatalog example project](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/getting-started/example-projects/).

If you contact us on [our official support page](https://pspdfkit.com/support/request) we can also offer you access to a nightly build so you can test this right away.